# Is MMSE equalizer necessary?

Tags: ofdm, equalization, channelcoding, fading-channel, equalizer

For observation $y$, channel coefficient $h$ and gaussian noise $w \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma^2)$,

$$y = hx + w \tag{1}$$

Note that for OFDM system, (1) is assumed channel input-ouput equation on each subcarrier after DFT. Without loss of generality, let assume $x$ is BPSK or QPSK modulated.

My question is about the usage of channel equalizers. The first one is Least Square equalizer: $y' = y/h, \tag{2}$

and the second one Linear MMSE (LMMSE) equalizer, which coincides with MMSE equalizer for Rayleigh channels,: $y' = y \frac{h^*}{||h||^2+\sigma^2} \tag{3}$

I agree that if we hard-decode $y'$, LMMSE equalizer has better Bit Error Rate (BER). However, as modern receivers use soft decoding, we need to calculate Log Likelihood ratio (LLR),

$$LLR = \log\frac{p(y|x=+1)}{p(y|x=-1)}, \tag{4}$$

*which depends on (1), somehow related to (2) in computing (4), and it is completely unnecessary to do (3).
Therefore, could I say that the LMMSE equalizer is useless?* Here I have assumed we have perfect channel estimation, but I doubt that the use of (3) is justified even with erroneous channel estimate.

(I can write down mathematical derivation of (4) using both (2) and (3) to show that the final results are identical. However, I think it is obvious enough with the above arguments.)

I appreciate any explaination and paper reference.